Broswer is not saving my Cookies that getting from login responce
i am using nodejs and jwt token system , after i login i am successfully gets my cookies in response but the browser is not saving them in storage cookies . this how i sending my cookies :-
return res
.status(200)
.cookie("accessToken", accessToken, options)
.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, options)
.json(
new ApiResponse(
200,
{
user: loggedInUser,
accessToken,
refreshToken,
},
"user logged In successfully",
),
); 

and here options is :-
const options = {
httpOnly: true,
secure: true,
}; 

and then u can see i am getting cookies in response :- cookies i am getting in response but not saving in browsercookies not saved in browser
i don't know how to solve this

There could be multiple reasons behind this behaviour, tho you can try some things to debug/troubleshoot the issue :

I see you've set the secure attribute to true, which means the
browser will only send the cookie over HTTPS connections. If
you're testing locally with HTTP (not HTTPS), the browser won't
save the cookies due to security restrictions.
One solution to this is to ensure that you're accessing your server
over HTTPS if you've set the secure attribute to true else try
modifying it to false.

By default, cookies are set for the current domain. If your server
is running on a different domain or subdomain than your frontend,
the browser might not save the cookies due to the Same-Origin
Policy.
Now to resolve this set the domain attribute explicitly to
the correct domain or subdomain where your frontend is hosted.

By default, cookies are set for the path of the current URL. If
your frontend is hosted on a different path than your backend, the
browser might not save the cookies correctly. To verify this, set
path attribute explicitly to the correct path where your frontend
is hosted.

Lastly, check your development environment make sure you're not testing on incognito mode, as some browsers may not save cookies in private mode.

Browser extensions like ad blockers or privacy tools might interfere with cookie saving. Try disabling any browser extensions that might interfere with cookie behaviour.


const options = {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true, // saves cookies on https connections
  domain: 'yourdomain.com', // define domain explicitly
  path: '/yourpath', // define path explicitly
};


no not working, any other way i can do
